# Are «una bandada de patos» and «ráfaga de viento» common phrases in Spain?

Tags: españa, expresiones

I'm trying to write some Spanish poems for a girl that I fell in love with. My Spanish is very basic and I have some doubts.

Do Spaniards say:

```
Una bandada de patos 

Ráfaga de viento
```

Comment: I have edited your question to focus it a little bit. We require that each post ask only a [single question](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2422/12), so I removed your question about the gender of the word «iris». That question would also likely get closed even if you asked it separately, because any Spanish dictionary will answer that question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, *"bandada de patos"* y *"ráfaga de viento"* son correctas.

*"Iris"* es masculino, por ejemplo:

> El iris de su ojo es de color verde.